# .Net Core 1.0 Relative Project Dependencies Not Found

Tags: .net-core, project.json

I have the project structure:

```
/src
  - common
    - common-x
      + project.json
  - module-a
    - project-a
      + project.json
    - project-a-tests
      + project.json
    + global.json
```

I'm trying to include the `common-x` project using relative file paths in the `global.json` file.

The `global.json` file in the `module-a` directory is as follows:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "project-a",
    "project-a-tests",
    "../common/common-x"
  ]
}
```

and the `project.json` file in `project-a` is

```
{
  // Default config options are also in this...

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "common-x": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  }
}
```

`project-a-tests` has no problem referencing `project-a` since they are in the same directory, but `project-a` can't find the `common-x` project. I receive a "Unable to resolve ..." error from `dotnet restore`.

I have tried using absolute paths but that doesn't work either. The closest solution so far is to use symlinks but that is not preferable.

Note: This is all being run on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to specify top level folders in your `global.json` file, since sub-folders will be scanned automatically. [Global.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json).

So your `global.json` should look like this.

```
{
    "projects": [ "src" ]
}
```

If you are still getting any dependencies issues that might related to compatibility problems between projects/modules, however I would need to see the exact output you are getting to troubleshoot that.

**UPDATE**

A few tips that might be useful:

- Delete old project.json.lock files
- Add a `.sln` solution file if you don't have one created.

**UPDATE 2**

As per your comment, the working solution was to move `global.json` into `src` folder, and list your top-level folders in the projects array.

Comment: This was very close to working. I had to add move the global.json file inside src and then add each top level folder (i.e. "common", and "module-a") to the projects array and then it worked. If you update your answer I can mark this as the solution.